# Javascript: return two parts of a string...

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Heres a quick one for you javascript magicians out there!

I have a string like so

```
var something="a<b>pple</b>";
```

Can you break the above apart so that I get an array like this:

```
the_string[0] would contain "a"
the_string[1] would contain "pple"
```

basically, the text **before** the tag and the text **in** the tag.
The tag will always be the bold tag and in that exact format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"a<b>pple</b>".split(/<\/?b>/)`

Comment: +1 So much nicer then where I was going with `match`. Too late in the day!

Answer (score 3):

```
var the_string = something.split(/<\/?b>/);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2FNr8/

Answer (score 0):

What if you wanted to keep everything but have it separated where the tags were so you'd have:

```
the_string[0] would contain "a"
the_string[1] would contain "<b>"
the_string[2] would contain "pple"
the_string[3] would contain "</b>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what the elements are, you can use:

```
function getTextAsArray(text) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = text;

  function getText (element) {
    var text = [];
    var el, els = element.childNodes;

    for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      el = els[i];

      if (el.nodeType == 1) {
        text.push(getText(el));

      } else if (el.nodeType == 3) {
        text.push(el.data);
      }
    }
    return text;
  }
  return getText(div);
}

alert(getTextAsArray("a<b>pple</b>")); // a, pple
```